# When should EntityManagerFactory instance be created/opened?

Tags: java, jpa, singleton, entitymanager

Ok, I read bunch of articles/examples how to write Entity Manager Factory in singleton.

One of them easiest for me to understand a bit:

http://javanotepad.blogspot.com/2007/05/jpa-entitymanagerfactory-in-web.html

I learned that **EntityManagerFactory (EMF) should only be created once preferably in application scope.**

And also make sure to close the EMF once it's used (?)

So I wrote EMF helper class for business methods to use:

```
public class EmProvider {

    private static final String DB_PU = "KogaAlphaPU";

    public static final boolean DEBUG = true;

    private static final EmProvider singleton = new EmProvider();

    private EntityManagerFactory emf;

    private EmProvider() {}

    public static EmProvider getInstance() {
        return singleton;
    }


    public EntityManagerFactory getEntityManagerFactory() {
        if(emf == null) {
            emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(DB_PU);
        }
        if(DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("factory created on: " + new Date());
        }
        return emf;
    }

    public void closeEmf() {
        if(emf.isOpen() || emf != null) {
            emf.close();
        }
        emf = null;
        if(DEBUG) {
            System.out.println("EMF closed at: " + new Date());
        }
    }

}//end class
```

**And my method using EmProvider:**

```
public String foo() {
    EntityManager em = null;
    List<Object[]> out = null;
    try {

        em = EmProvider.getInstance().getEntityManagerFactory().createEntityManager();
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery(JPQL_JOIN); //just some random query 
        out = query.getResultList();
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        //handle error....
    }
    finally {
        if(em != null) {
             em.close(); //make sure to close EntityManager
        }
        //should I not close the EMF itself here?????
        EmProvider.getInstance().closeEmf();
    }
```

I made sure to close EntityManager (em) within method level as suggested. But **when should EntityManagerFactory be closed then?** And why EMF has to be singleton so bad??? I read about concurrency issues but as I am not experienced multi-thread-grammer, I can't really be clear on this idea.

Comment: "And why EMF has to be singleton so bad???" this statement i should probably open another question....

Answer (score 62, accepted):

- EntityManagerFactory instances are
  heavyweight objects. Each factory
  might maintain a metadata cache,
  object state cache, EntityManager
  pool, connection pool, and more. If
  your application no longer needs an
  EntityManagerFactory, you should
  close it to free these resources.
- When an EntityManagerFactory closes,
  all EntityManagers from that factory,
  and by extension all entities managed
  by those EntityManagers, become
  invalid.
- It is much better to keep a factory
  open for a long period of time than
  to repeatedly create and close new
  factories. Thus, most applications
  will never close the factory, or only
  close it when the application is
  exiting.
- Only applications that require
  multiple factories with different
  configurations have an obvious reason
  to create and close multiple
  EntityManagerFactory instances.
- Only one EntityManagerFactory is
  permitted to be created for each
  deployed persistence unit
  configuration. Any number of
  EntityManager instances may be
  created from a given factory.
- More than one entity manager factory
  instance may be available
  simultaneously in the JVM. Methods of the EntityManagerFactory
  interface are threadsafe.

Comment: I think 'EntityManagerFactory' should not be closed for an online web application.

Comment: It should be closed but only when the web application stops (user stops it or undeploys it). Example: Implementing contextDestroyed method from ServletContextListener interface when using JSF

Comment: @pvm14 Yes, definitely. If have to go by your way & if its there everything in the documentation & everybody understands, stackoverlow wouldn't have came into the picture. People haven't voted unnecessarily. If you don't like, leave it, refrain from posting irrelevant comments, instead try adding more information, details, mistakes etc. if you can, which would help everyone.

Comment: the only problem I have with the answer is that, in my admittedly limited experience, it's actually required to open/close the EMF -- at least from clients, otherwise the client will just hang without even logging an error.  Perhaps the performance is different when JPA runs from the server.

Comment: @Thufir Already mentioned EntityManagerFactory instance is a heavyweight object & should be created only once at the application initialization & closed when undelpoyed/terminated. If there are numerous clients, opening/closing factory instance is not preferable.