# Test two PersistenceContexts for equality

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, equality

**Is there a way to check if two EntityManagers instances represents the same PersistenceContext?**

The container can use a proxy for implementation of the EntityManager, so I don't think that checking the reference of the injected EntityManager and comparing it (in other words doing "==" comparison) is enough to say that it represents the same PersistenceContext, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have debugged the scenario with two entity managers with `@PersistenceContext`

- When injected persistent context with same unit, comparing `entityManager.getDelegate()` which returns the vendor specific underlying object are same & both points to the same entity manager factory.
- With different units, the delegates obtained & entity manager factory, both were different.

Further can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4544053/366964) post.

Note : The environment used is Java EE 5, there were several other methods like `getMetaModel()`, `unwrap(object)`, `getProperties()` etc. can provide further information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time and answer! I started to thought that no one is interested in this stuff :-) I will gather information I get from other sources (i.e. Glassfish mailing list) and add it here as well.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to sum up information I was able to get from Glassfish mailing list, Eclipselink forum and Nayan Wadekar response and published it [here](http://piotrnowicki.com/2011/11/am-i-in-the-same-transaction-am-i-using-the-same-persistencecontext/).

In short: you can compare unwrapped JPA provider `EntityManager`s which will give you more adequate information than application server `EntityManager`.
Other way would be to check for Transaction Key to see if you're using the same transaction in different methods. If so, then it implies that you must be using the same `PersistenceContext`.