# JPA persistence units

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpa-2.0, entitymanager

If you're using container managed persistence, and you look up a persistence unit by its JNDI name (as defined in ejb-jar.xml in the persistence-context-ref):

(i.e. `EntityManager manager = (EntityManager) context.lookup(jndiName);` )

Is it an EMF associated with the PU behind the scene pumping out EMs, or is it just a global EM linked to a single thread?

I ask because I want to decouple persistence unit management from my DAOs, and this would be possible if it's a new EM each time, but if it's the same one, and EMs are not thread-safe, then I can't share it between 30 services.

Debugging shows it is an JpaTxEntityManager being returned, which I see is some sort of proxy object, but I can't find anywhere about how the mechanism is actually handled behind the scenes.

Does anyone know?
Thanks

Comment: Can refer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/4544053/366964

Comment: your documentation refers to application managed persistence unfortunately.  Any time you create an EMF you forego container management.

Comment: If you are looking it up from JNDI, I believe you are probably letting the container place it there, so they are container managed.  The code you have shown references an EntityManager, not an EMF.  If you get an EMF and use it to obtain EntityManagers, you are responsible for their lifecycle and should not share them.

Comment: Yeah, It gives you an EM, not an EMF.  

It's container managed, and it's giving me an EntityManager.  So I want to know what is this EntityManager?  Is it a new one, or one that 30 other threads have a reference to?